One thing I don't understand about the diode graph

I have such a circuit.
I need to determine the output when such an input is given.
But the only thing I understand is the way I have drawn it below.

The current enters from the negative direction. Since it is connected inversely with the voltage, it is open circuit. Then I could not find how to draw the output graph, could you help me?
editing: I think that since the voltage value is zero, the current value is also zero, then I don't know how to proceed.

hm. So, if it's an open circuit, then how much current flows through the resistor? And what does Ohm's law say about the voltage across the resistor then? Please add that information, or where you're stuck with that, to your question by editing it (don't just comment, please).

I did some editing but I think my problem is clear

but then I don't understand why you cannot know how to proceed. You say the voltage is zero – so, draw that into the output diagram.

@manrupe See these additions to see if this helps you at all.

When Vin=20V the Vout is 0V because diode is reversed.
When Vin=-5V the Vout is -3V because 2V source creates an offset.
